# Java Swing: consuming key events

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame (containing various text fields and tables etc.) and want to install a hot key function that applies whenever the frame is open (a bit like a menu accelerator shortcut). The following mostly works, and my action is invoked regardless of which field or control has focus:

```
String MY_GLOBAL_ACTION_TRIGGER = "hotKey";
InputMap im = getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('`');
im.put(ks, MY_GLOBAL_ACTION_TRIGGER);
ActionMap am = getRootPane().getActionMap();
am.put(MY_ACTION_TRIGGER, new AbstractAction() { public void actionPerformed() ... });
```

However, the key press isn't consumed and I still get a back quote inserted into the text field. How can I prevent the key press being propagated to text fields once my action has been invoked?

Answer (score 2):

Use the KeyboardFocusManager and a KeyEventDispatcher

```
private void myListener implements KeyEventDispatcher {
  public boolean dispatchKeyEvent (KeyEvent ke) {
    if (ke.getKeyChar() == '`') {
      MY_GLOBAL_ACTION.actionPerformed(null);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Beware, this won't catch the use case where the user pastes text into the field...

Comment: 1+ for handling a hot key. If the KeyEvent is not dispatched then you don't have to worry about it being dispatched to other components.

Answer (score 2):

It is likely the text fields are getting precedence on the key event notification, meaning your key binding isn't getting notified until after the text field has been updated

Generally speaking, you really don't want to monitor key strokes/events on text components, as it does not take into consideration the use case where the user pastes text into field

If you want to filter content going into textField you should use a `DocumentFilter`

See [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter)

Comment: I'm not interested in monitoring events on individual text components, I'm trying to handle key events on the window as a whole (a bit like a menu accelerator shortcut).

Comment: What you're interested in and what you can achieve are distinct issues.  Text components process key events before key bindings and other key listeners, generally. The `DocumentFilter` processes the content before it's submitted to the `Document`, including the use-case of the user pasting text into the field. Consuming events may also not be enough, as some key processes can ignore the consumed state as well.  You will need to decide what works...

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

The `KeyStroke` constructed with `char` argument doesn't seem to actually catch the stroke. Try using `KeyStroke(KeyEvent key, int modifiers)`.

The textfields should filter the selected stroke, or rather a listener should consume them.

Try something like:

```
public class KeyStrokeFrame extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new KeyStrokeFrame().setVisible(true);
    }

    public KeyStrokeFrame() {
        setSize(200, 200);
        JTextField jtf = new JTextField();
        getContentPane().add(jtf);
        String MY_GLOBAL_ACTION_TRIGGER = "hotKey";
        InputMap im = getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        KeyStroke ks = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0);
        ((AbstractDocument)jtf.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                    String string, AttributeSet attr)
                    throws BadLocationException {
                if (string.equals("1")) return;
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
                    String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                    throws BadLocationException {
                if (text.equals("1")) return;
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
        });
        im.put(ks, MY_GLOBAL_ACTION_TRIGGER);
        ActionMap am = getRootPane().getActionMap();
        am.put(MY_GLOBAL_ACTION_TRIGGER, new AbstractAction() { 
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("pressed");} 
            }); 
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my code wasn't very clear, I'd left out adding an action handler to the action map. I've updated the code now. Thanks for that.